# How to add a new Product details in existing Amazon Order ID in Amazon MWS API

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I want to add an SKU to an existing Amazon Order.
My code is as follows:

```
 <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>UNIQUE-TO-ME-1234</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B000A0S46M</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Above code is to add a new Product but I don't know how to add an item\product to an Amazon orderId.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. Is this supposed to be a snippet?

Comment: My XML is well-formed now.